# How can i multiply all the numbers by 10 in java file I/O

Tags: java, file-io

Okay, so I have to Write a program to create a file named Lab13.txt. Write ten integers ranging [0, 99] created randomly into the file using text I/O.  Integers are separated by spaces in the file.  Read the data back from the file and display them on the console.
I've done this part already, but next I have to take those numbers in that file, create a new file, multiply all the numbers in the Lab13.txt file, and store them in the new file. My problem is when i create the new file, I'm only able to get it to multiply the last number printed from the Lab13.txt file. How do i get it to multiply all the numbers in Lab13.txt file by 10 and print them? This is probably a really simple solution and I feel so dumb for not being able to figure it out. Creating files is the new thing we're learning and my teacher is little to no help. :(

```
import java.io.*;

public class Lab13 {

    public static void main(String ar[]) {

        String toWrite = "";
        int x=0;
        try {

            File file=new File("Lab13.txt");
            FileWriter filewriter=new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                x=(int)(Math.random()*100);
                writer.write(" "+x);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            File file1=new File("Lab13.txt");
            FileReader filereader=new FileReader(file1);
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(filereader);
            String y;
            while((y=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(y);
                toWrite += ("" + x*10);
                System.out.println(toWrite);
            }

        File output = new File("lab13_scale.txt");
        if(!output.exists()) output.createNewFile();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(output.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bWriter= new BufferedWriter(writer);
        bWriter.write(toWrite);
        bWriter.close();
      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: First do not use `x` stemming from the prior read. `y` contains the current line with numbers. So you need to get every number from the line. And mind multiplying by ten would simply be adding a "0" with the exception for the number "0".

Comment: You need to loop through your numbers...right now you are taking `x` which is the last number added to the file. You need to `split` your line into an array and parse each element to an integer then multiply each one by 10.

Comment: You could just add `0` to every word. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while((y=reader.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(y);
    toWrite += ("" + x*10);
    System.out.println(toWrite);
}
```

What `reader.readLine()` tells the reader to do is look for every newline character "\n" and process the chunks of text in between, and since you didnt add any, it treats the whole file as a single chunk.

What you can do instead is read the entire contents of the file into a string and then split it with the space delimiter (below is untested code):

```
String s = reader.readLine();
String[] allNumbers = s.split(" ");
for(String number : allNumbers) {
    int currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
    bWriter.write(String.valueOf(currentNumber * 10) + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're never reading individual numbers from that line. And the `x` you multiplied with 10 was the last number you randomly generated in previous loop. That's why the problem.

Remove line -

`toWrite += ("" + x*10);`

Replace with -

`String numArray = y.split(" ");
for (int i=0; i<numArray.length; i++) {
    int newNum = Integer.parseInt(numArray[i]) * 10;
    toWrite += ("" + newNum);
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public void multiply() throws Exception{
    //reading from existing file
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Lab13.txt"));
    String l = br.readLine(); //assuming from your code that there is only one line
    br.flush();
    br.close();
    String[] arr = l.split(" ");
    //writing into new_file.txt
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("new_file.txt"));
    for(String a : arr){
            bw.write((Integer.parseInt(a)*10) + " ");
    }
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
```

Just call this method. Should work. You basically need to split the String using space. once that done, parsing each String into Integer and multiplying. and again storing.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.io.*;

public class Lab13
{

    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        String toWrite = "";
        int x = 0;
        try
        {
            File file = new File("Lab13.txt");
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                x = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                writer.write(" " + x);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try
        {
            File file1 = new File("Lab13.txt");
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file1);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
            String y;
            while ((y = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                ////////////////////////////////////////

                //trim - delete leading spaces from y
                String[] array = y.trim().split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
                    System.out.println(number);
                    toWrite += (number * 10 + " ");

                }
                System.out.println(toWrite);
                ////////////////////////////////////////
            }


            File output = new File("lab13_scale.txt");
            if (!output.exists()) output.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(output.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            bWriter.write(toWrite);
            bWriter.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```